# How many blocks and nodes can i run on a local Hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using Hyperledger explorer for checking the fabric blocks, transactions, Chaincodes and nodes.

My System configuration is :
RAM: 12GB, 
Processor: i5-7th gen
Memory: 1TB

Answer (score 0):

You can run at ~12 peers. The bottleneck will be RAM. I have noticed each peer requires roughly 1GB of RAM. 1TB should be able to handle a large amount of blocks. You can see how big each block is by inspecting the docker volumes. The block size is also configurable.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, by configuring block size do you mean the structure of block i.e the data stored in it?

Comment: yes - I believe he means configuring how many transactions are written before a block is cut.  See more info in the docs https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/config_update.html?highlight=block%20size#editing-a-config or the  answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336505/what-is-the-size-of-the-default-block-on-hyperldger-fabric/50997556